# Store picture on sd directory problem

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using the follow code to take a picture using the native camera:

```
private File mImageFile;
private String mTempImagePath;
public static Uri imageUri;
public void imageFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        Log.d("fototemp", "No SDCARD");
    } else {
        mImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"testFolder", "Pic"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(mImageFile);

        DataClass dc = (DataClass) getApplicationContext();
        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"testFolder");
        Uri tempUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
        dc.setString(DataClass.IMAGE_PATH, tempUri.toString());
        Log.d("fototemp", "ImagePath: " + tempUri.toString());


        mTempImagePath = mImageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mImageFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}
```

The ImagePath I print out in the imageFromCamera() method is: 4file:///file%3A/mnt/sdcard/testFolder

Now when I try to access these foto's by using managedQuery I get a different directory. 
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() gives content://media/external/images/thumbnails

What is the difference between these 2 paths? And how can I get the managedQuery to go to the testFolder map to look for pictures?

edit:
I'm trying to connect:

```
Uri phoneUriII = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"testFolder");
imagecursor = managedQuery(phoneUriII, img, null,null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
```

but this code crashes

Comment: Do you mean you want to get a real image path from the Url object? Like [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-file-path-of-gallery-image)?

Comment: I want the folder where I save my pictures to be converted to an Uri so I can pass i to the managedQuery method.. I think

Comment: Can't you just use the Url that you get from MediaStore to retrieve the binary stream? Try calling getData() on it or using `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)`.

Comment: I've tried this too ( Uri temp = Uri.parse(data.toURI());
              Log.d("fototemp", data.toURI());) 

but it prints "Foto taken: #Intent;action=inline-data;end" which isnt the proper path either. Totally confused about this topic

Answer (score 0):

Sorry don't really understand your question.

Just send this as the URI path.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"testFolder"

Also
Check if you have the permissions to write to the sd card.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: the writing isn't the problem because I can view the taken photos in the gallery. I'm trying Uri phoneUriII = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"testFolder"); imagecursor = managedQuery(phoneUriII, img, null,null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + ""); but this crashes

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function in a couple of projects and it works fine.

```
/**
 * Retrieves physical path to the image from content Uri
 * @param contentUri
 * @return
 */
private String getRealImagePathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```